# Prompt input until a mimimum number of values is entered

Tags: c++, c++11, input, visual-c++, io

I am writing a small program in which I have to search for smallest and largest element entered.

The thing is I have made an array 10 elements wide and the user should enter at least 5 element.

If the user enter less than 5 elements I want to prompt insufficient elements.

This is the code I have written but it's not working:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10], largest, smallest, i = 1, j = 1;
    cout << "Enter the values in array at least 5 and maximum 10 " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    while (arr[i] >= 5)
    {
        largest = arr[0];
        smallest = arr[0];

        if (largest <= arr[j])
        {
            largest = arr[j];
        }

        if (smallest > arr[j])
        {
            smallest = arr[j];
        }

        j++;
        i++;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please share what is the exact error you are getting. Simply posting code will not help you.

Comment: User has no choice but to input 10 times. While loop Boolean expression appears completely arbitrary.

Comment: If the size of your array is unknown at compile-time, use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: You need to check while reading how many numbers are input. You can't examine the array to determine how many elements you assigned to.

Comment: @ Vagish it doesnt check without the condition it works and give largest and smallest value accurately but not with condition

Comment: @ sweenish any way to fix it

Comment: @ m88 i have assigned the size to array

Comment: @ molbdnilo you are suggesting i have to add an 'if' condition during 'cin'?

Answer (score 1):

This code demonstrates how you'd find the min and max of a `std::vector`. The same principles apply to arrays. This piece of code does not allow a variable number of inputs.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // std::min_element() & std::max_element
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  // Set up; Fills vector with 10 random digits in range [1, 10]
  std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 10);

  std::vector<int> numbers(10);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
    numbers[i] = dist(prng);
  }

  // Find minimum and maximum, the easy way
  auto min = std::min_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
  auto max = std::max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

  // Find minimum and maximum, the hard way
  int minIdx = 0;
  int maxIdx = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
    if (numbers[i] < numbers[minIdx]) minIdx = i;
    if (numbers[i] > numbers[maxIdx]) maxIdx = i;
  }

  // Print all numbers to verify
  for (auto i : numbers) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }

  // This print goes with the std::min_element approach
  std::cout << "\nMin: " << *min << "\nMax: " << *max << '\n';

  // This print goes with the for loop approach
  std::cout << "\nMin: " << numbers[minIdx] << "\nMax: " << numbers[maxIdx]
            << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 5 2 10 2 8 6 7 6 7 
Min: 1
Max: 10

Min: 1
Max: 10
```

In both methods, *WHERE* the min and max are stored are what's recorded. The first method returns an iterator, and the for-loop method records the index. It's more valuable to know where your min and max are versus just knowing the value.

The deal with a variable number of inputs *and* requiring a minimum is that things get complicated very quickly. The easiest, but not greatest (subjective) approach is to use a sentinel value. It's something the user must type to indicate that they are done typing. The wrinkle here that throws that out a bit is the fact that the user can enter the number 10. So I kind of pull out some bigger guns to handle this. A nice thing about the big guns is that they don't require a sentinel value. The user can just press Enter.

The code below uses a C-array like you, and it is a lot more tedious because of it. `std::vector`s know their size, and you can just add elements to it. With a C-array, you have to track the size separately, make sure it's always correct, etc. I lose the ability to use range-based for loops since the array may be only partially utilized.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // std::min_element() & std::max_element
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int main() {
  constexpr int capacity = 10;
  int numbers[capacity];
  int size = 0;
  std::string tmp;
  while (size < capacity && std::getline(std::cin, tmp)) {
    if (tmp == "" && size >= 5) {
      break;
    }
    if (tmp == "" && size < 5) {
      std::cerr << "Need at least 5 elements.\n";
      continue;
    }

    std::size_t pos;
    int num;
    try {
      num = std::stoi(tmp, &pos);
    } catch (...) {
      std::cerr << "Exception thrown.\n";
      continue;
    }
    if (pos != tmp.length()) {
      std::cerr << "Bad Value.\n";
      continue;
    }

    if (num >= 0 && num <= 10) {
      numbers[size] = num;
      ++size;
    }
  }

  // Find minimum and maximum, the easy way
  auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(numbers), std::begin(numbers) + size);
  auto max = std::max_element(std::begin(numbers), std::begin(numbers) + size);

  // Find minimum and maximum, the hard way
  int minIdx = 0;
  int maxIdx = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (numbers[i] < numbers[minIdx]) minIdx = i;
    if (numbers[i] > numbers[maxIdx]) maxIdx = i;
  }

  // Print all numbers to verify
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    std::cout << numbers[i] << ' ';
  }

  // This print goes with the std::min_element approach
  std::cout << "\nMin: " << *min << "\nMax: " << *max << '\n';

  // This print goes with the for loop approach
  std::cout << "\nMin: " << numbers[minIdx] << "\nMax: " << numbers[maxIdx]
            << '\n';
}
```

You can tell how much extra work is required just for basic ASCII input. If you make some assumptions, a lot of the code can be cut out, but where user input is concerned, those assumptions are rarely safe, and are more of a convenience for quick testing or learning purposes.

Comment: Don't worry, I like for my code to be correct when I post and appreciate the review.

Comment: I've edited. I think both programs should function correctly.

Comment: What? My testing was limited, but I was getting correct messages for < 5 inputs, and between 5 and 10, and it stops after the tenth. What were your inputs? I'm only allowing numbers in the range [0, 10].

Comment: If OP provides more information on whether there is a specific range or not, and how the input is provided, I can definitely make changes. I think the second example is already more complicated than what OP is supposed to be turning in.

Comment: I'm satisfied with it, won't bother you further, you already spent way too much time on this.